# Hide button on outside div tap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to have a button no longer be show when the user isn't interacting with it or it's not the user's focus. I am using react right now in the project

In a desktop setting I accomplish this by saying `onmouseleave={this.hideButton}` but I'm having a tougher time with the iPad. I've tried `onTouchCancel={this.hideButton}` but haven't gotten lucky.

I looked at [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#touch-events) and see there's a touchTarget list, but I don't see any documentation on how to access these properties, am I going down the right path by looking trying to do it this way?

What I've tried before was having the `body` element listen with an onClick event and hide the button if it's showing but this didn't work as clicking on the button when it was showing would display the modal that I wanted to appear on button click.

I should also note that `this.hideButton` just changes a boolean value from true to false.

Any advice?

Note: This is a project for work where we've decided NOT to use jQuery (not my call)

Here is what it looks like currently:

```
toggleLogoutButton() {
    this.setState({
        logoutButtonVisible: this.props.shouldShowLogoutButton
        && !this.state.logoutButtonVisible,
    });
}

logoutButtonAction() {
    this.toggleLogoutButton();
    this.props.showModal();
}

hideLogoutButton() {
    if (this.state.logoutButtonVisible) {
        this.setState({
            logoutButtonVisible: false,
        });
    }
}

render() {
  return(
  <div className="some-style-1" >
  <span 
  className="some-style-2" 
  onClick={this.toggleLogoutButton}>{this.props.text}
  {this.props.shouldShowLogoutButton && this.caretRender()}
  {this.state.logoutButtonVisible &&
      <div className="dropmenu show" 
      onClick={this.logoutButtonAction}
      onMouseLeave={this.hideLogoutButton}
      onTouchEnd={this.hideLogoutButton}>
         Log Out
      </div>}
   </span>
 </div>);
}
```

Comment: If the button is hidden, how user will know its there?

Comment: Let's say we have some element on the screen which contains a "drop down" button for example, user clicks on said element, variable `displayButton` is true, button is showing. User clicks somewhere else on screen, we want `displayButton` to be set to false. except this is on an iPad, so treating it like a click event won't work. @DenisMatafonov does that clarify the situation?

Answer (score 0):

### Please include more pieces of your code!

In order to diagnose what you need, we need to see what you have already.

First off, change

`onMouseLeave={this.hideButton};`

to (assuming your button name has `id="button-name"`),

`$('#button-name').onMouseLeave={this.hide()};`

Depending on how you want your button to show/hide, I wouldn't suggest using this. Instead, turn the button to `disabled=true`. If you hide it, it will be gone and will no longer be able to be reached by `onMouseEnter`.

For example,

`$('#button-name').onMouseLeave={this.disabled=true;};`

With that said, hiding (and even disabled a button onMouseLeave...) does not make much sense.